# JAVA Swing JButton ActionPerformed method implementation .getSource method

Tags: java, swing

I'm a beginner in Java Swing. I was trying to create a simple calculator that only has + and -. I used JButtons, for "+" and "-" and added actionListener to respond to each button. However, I can't really understand why the e.getSource() is not working. Is it a dynamic dispatch problem? I would really appreciate a help!!

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

class MenuExample implements ActionListener {
    // JMenu menu1, menu2, menu3;
    // JMenuItem i1, i2, i3, i4, i5;
    JTextArea t1, t2;
    JTextField t3;
    JButton b1, b2;

    MenuExample() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Menu and MenuItem EX");
        final JButton b1 = new JButton("+"); 
        final JButton b2 = new JButton("-");
        t3 = new JTextField();t3.setBounds(50, 350, 200, 30); t3.setEditable(false);
        t1 = new JTextArea(); t1.setBounds(50,100,200,30);
        t2 = new JTextArea(); t2.setBounds(50,250,200,30);
        b1.addActionListener(this);
        b2.addActionListener(this); 
        b1.setBounds(50, 450, 30, 30); b2.setBounds(100, 450, 30, 30); 
        f.add(b1); f.add(b2);f.add(t1); f.add(t2); f.add(t3);

        f.setSize(800, 800);
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton button;
        int answer=0;
        String s1 = t1.getText(); 
        String s2 = t2.getText();
        int a = Integer.parseInt(s1);
        int b = Integer.parseInt(s2);

        Object source = e.getSource();
        if (source instanceof JButton) {
            button = (JButton) source;
            System.out.println("called here at least?");
            System.out.println(button.getClass());
            if (button == b1) {
                answer = a + b;
            }
            else if (button == b2) {
                answer = a - b;
            }
        }
        String result = String.valueOf(answer);
        t3.setText(result);
    }
}

public class JMenuPractice {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        new MenuExample();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're shadowing your b1 and b2 JButton fields by re-declaring them in the constructor:

```
class MenuExample implements ActionListener {
    JTextArea t1, t2;
    JTextField t3;
    JButton b1, b2;  // these stay null!!!

    MenuExample() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Menu and MenuItem EX");

        // Don't re-declare the variables here!
        final JButton b1 = new JButton("+");  
        final JButton b2 = new JButton("-");
```

This leaves the fields null and your equality test in the listener won't work. The solution: don't shadow! Instead use the fields that you already have:

```
class MenuExample implements ActionListener {
    JTextArea t1, t2;
    JTextField t3;
    JButton b1, b2;  // these are no longer null

    MenuExample() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Menu and MenuItem EX");

        // final JButton b1 = new JButton("+"); 
        // final JButton b2 = new JButton("-");
        b1 = new JButton("+");
        b2 = new JButton("-");
```

Note the huge difference?

Other issues:

- Don't use null layouts and `setBounds`. While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.
- Consider using anonymous inner classes for your listeners. Then you won't even need to use `.getSource()`

Because of your use of null layouts and `setBounds`, this is what your GUI looks like when I run it:

[image]

If you used layouts and anonymous listeners, the code could look like the GUI below. Note that I like to use JSpinners and not JTextFields for input since this restricts the input to numbers:

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SimpleCalc extends JPanel {
    private static final int GAP = 4;
    private JSpinner spinner1 = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, -1000, 1000, 1));
    private JSpinner spinner2 = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, -1000, 1000, 1));
    private JTextField resultField = new JTextField(10);
    private JButton addButton = new JButton("+");
    private JButton subtractButton = new JButton("-");

    public SimpleCalc() {
        // add anonymous listeners to each JButton
        addButton.addActionListener(e -> add());
        subtractButton.addActionListener(e -> subtract());

        // put both buttons within a JPanel that uses grid layout
        // 1 row, variable number of columns, gap between components
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, GAP, GAP));
        buttonPanel.add(addButton);
        buttonPanel.add(subtractButton);

        resultField.setFocusable(false);
        resultField.setEditable(false);

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));
        // use GridBagLayout
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        // start at x position is 0, and stay there
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        // y position increments each time
        gbc.gridy = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
        // stretch components horizontally not vertically
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        // gap between componentns
        gbc.insets = new Insets(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP);

        add(spinner1, gbc);
        add(spinner2, gbc);
        add(resultField, gbc);
        add(buttonPanel, gbc);
    }

    public void add() {
        int value1 = (int) spinner1.getValue();
        int value2 = (int) spinner2.getValue();
        int result = value1 + value2;
        resultField.setText(String.valueOf(result));
    }

    public void subtract() {
        int value1 = (int) spinner1.getValue();
        int value2 = (int) spinner2.getValue();
        int result = value1 - value2;
        resultField.setText(String.valueOf(result));
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        SimpleCalc mainPanel = new SimpleCalc();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleCalc");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

which displays as:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for this helpful answer!! For alternatives to using setBounds and null layout, would you just use the layout managers? like flowLayout and BorderLayout?

Comment: @ChatSev: yes you could use BorderLayout and FlowLayout. I often nest JPanels, each using its own layout. The example above uses both GridLayout and GridBagLayout. Read the [Layout Manager Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more.

Answer (score 0):

In the `actionPerformed` function you are using the `JButtons` `b1` and `b2` declared as `Class members` and that's no problem, but you should notice that you declared new `JButton`s `b1` and `b2` in your `Constructor` :

```
 final JButton b1 = new JButton("+"); 
 final JButton b2 = new JButton("-");
```

The `ActionListener` is attached to those two, not the ones declared as `Class members` which you're using in `actionPerformed()`.

So instead of shadowing them just do this :

```
b1 = new JButton("+"); 
b2 = new JButton("-");
```